# How to send parameter in REST api in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**How to send parameter in REST api in xamarin.forms ?**

I have created REST API Project in xamarin using PCL.

When I call Simple REST api using Below code in Xamarin.forms (Portable Class Library) then I have Successfully receive json Response.

```cs
using (var cl = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await cl.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.1.100/apps/jara/web/api/user/test");
    jsonResponseClass des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResponseClass>(result);
    lbl1.Text = des.code + " " + des.status + " " + des.message;
}

public class jsonResponseClass
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Using above code I got a response

```js
{
    code: 200,
    status: "ok",
    message: "hello"
}
```

REST API response type is **JSON** and type is **POST**

Now, I want to call below **Login** Api using paramater.

**http://192.168.1.100/apps/jara/web/api/user/login**

**Paramater :** **email_id** and **Password**

this api success response type is....

```js
{
    code: 200,
    status: "Success",
    User: {
        userid: 126,
        token: "d154s4d54s654df5s4df56s4df564s5df4",
        email: "shahbuddin@gmail.com",
        mobile_number: "9898989898"
    },
    message: "Successfully logged in"
}
```

What can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i can do this using below code....

```
using (var cl = new HttpClient())
{
    var formcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("email_id","shahbuddin@peerbits.com"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","shah")
        });


    var request = await cl.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.100/apps/jara/web/api/user/login", formcontent);

    request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    jsonResponselogin res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResponselogin>(response);

    lbl1.Text = res.code + " " + res.status + " " + res.message;

}
```

This code helpful for Calling **REST API** with Parameter

Thank you...